# Multiplying big numbers using Karatsuba's method

Tags: performance, algorithm, recursion, assembly, x86

The [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), first published in 1962, aims to speed up the [multiplication of big numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm) by reducing the number of 'single-digit-multiplications' involved.

Because of its complexity (overhead) this method is not particularly fast on the 'smaller' numbers. There's a threshold to be observed. Computing MAX_UINT<sup>**2**</sup>, I found this threshold to be at some 5000 decimal digits (in the product) before Karatsuba's becomes faster than my version of the classical long multiplication.

The multi-precision *mpMul* procedure that I present below requires 5 parameters passed on the stack.

- The 1st param specifies the precision (length in bits) of both the inputs which must be a power of 2, so one of \$\lbrace 2^5, 2^6, \ldots,  2^{30}, 2^{31}\rbrace\$.
- The 2nd param points to the 1st input aka multiplicand.
- The 3rd param points to the 2nd input aka multiplier.
- The 4th param points to where the **double length** result needs to go.
- The 5th param points to a scratch buffer for storing intermediate results.

The address of the double length product is returned in the `EAX` register and the carry flag will be set if the result exceeds the precision.

In an effort to make this procedure efficient I applied the following:

- Considering `EAX`, `EBX`, `ECX`, and `EDX` volatile registers reduced the recursion overhead a lot. This was especially important on the lowest level (the one with the `mul` instruction) that after all represents two thirds of all the `call`'s that are made.
- I refrained from using `EBP` as a stackframe pointer, instead I used `ESP` relative addressing. I think the extra byte for the 'sib-encoding' was well spent since an additional register to play with makes programming a bit easier.
- Because the recursive subroutine **does not remove its parameters when it returns**, I could simply re-use these parameters several times (with minimal changes).
- Instead of liberally assigning local variables and probably obtaining code that is nicer to look at or at least easier to follow, I squeezed as much as I could in the scratch buffer, re-assigning fields whenever possible.

[image: How the scratch buffer is organized]

```
; ------------------------------------
; Multiplying using Karatsuba's method
; ------------------------------------
; IN (stack) OUT (eax,CF) MOD (stack)
mpMul:  pushad
        mov     esi, [esp+32+4]      ;Precision {32, 64, 128, ... }
        shr     esi, 5               ;Bits -> dwords
        mov     eax, [esp+32+4+4]    ;Multiplicand
        mov     ebx, [esp+32+4+8]    ;Multiplier
        mov     edx, [esp+32+4+16]   ;Scratch buffer
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        push    ebx eax edx esi
        call    .MULT                ; -> (EAX EBX ECX EDX)
        pop     ecx esi
        add     esp, 8
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        imul    edx, ecx, 4          ;Distance between halves of result
        mov     edi, [esp+32+4+12]   ;Double length result
        mov     [esp+28], edi        ;pushad.EAX
        xor     ebp, ebp
@@:     mov     eax, [esi+edx]
        mov     [edi+edx], eax
        or      ebp, eax             ;Gathers every bit from upper half
        movsd
        dec     ecx
        jnz     @b
        cmp     ecx, ebp             ;Sets CF if upper half is non-zero
        popad
        ret     20
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; Recursive subroutine
; IN (stack) OUT (stack) MOD (eax,ebx,ecx,edx)
.MULT:  mov     ecx, [esp+4]         ;1st incoming arg is IntSize in dwords
        shr     ecx, 1
        jnz     @f

        mov     ecx, [esp+4+4]       ;2nd incoming arg is Scratch
        mov     eax, [esp+4+8]       ;3rd incoming arg is N1
        mov     ebx, [esp+4+12]      ;4th incoming arg is N2
        mov     eax, [eax]
        mul     dword [ebx]
        mov     [ecx], eax
        mov     [ecx+4], edx
        ret

@@:     push    esi edi ebp          ;12 bytes => [esp+12]
        mov     esi, ecx

        mov     edi, [esp+12+4+4]    ;2nd incoming arg is Scratch
        push    edi                  ;4th outgoing param
        mov     edx, [esp+4+12+4+12] ;4th incoming arg is N2
        call    .SUM                 ; -> EDI EBP (EAX EBX EDX)
        push    edi                  ;3rd outgoing param
        mov     edx, [esp+8+12+4+8]  ;3rd incoming arg is N1
        call    .SUM                 ; -> EDI EBP (EAX EBX EDX)
        push    edi                  ;2nd outgoing param
        push    esi                  ;1st outgoing param
        call    .MULT                ;H=Trunc(a+b)*Trunc(c+d) -> (EAX..EDX)
        xor     eax, eax
        and     ebp, 11b             ;Test both overflow conditions
        jnp     @f
        setnz   al                   ;Only set if both Trunc's lost 1 bit
@@:     mov     [edi+esi*8], eax     ;Setup dword after DoubleLengthProduct
        shr     ebp, 1               ;If Trunc(a+b) did loose 1 bit
        jnc     @f                   ; then adding Trunc(c+d) is needed.
        mov     ebx, [esp+12]        ;Trunc(c+d)
        call    .CURE                ; -> (EAX..EDX)
@@:     shr     ebp, 1               ;If Trunc(c+d) did loose 1 bit
        jnc     @f                   ; then adding Trunc(a+b) is needed.
        mov     ebx, [esp+8]         ;Trunc(a+b)
        call    .CURE                ; -> (EAX..EDX)

@@:     mov     eax, [esp+16+12+4+12];4th incoming arg is N2.d
        mov     [esp+12], eax
        mov     eax, [esp+16+12+4+8] ;3rd incoming arg is N1.b
        mov     [esp+8], eax
        lea     eax, [esi*8+4]
        add     [esp+4], eax         ;Memory above H
        call    .MULT                ;G=b*d -> (EAX..EDX)
        mov     edx, [esp+16+12+4+4] ;2nd incoming arg is Scratch
        mov     ebx, [esp+4]         ;G
        call    .DIF                 ;H-=G R=G -> (EAX ECX EBP)

        imul    eax, esi, 4
        add     [esp+12], eax        ;N2.c
        add     [esp+8], eax         ;N1.a
        call    .MULT                ;F=a*c -> (EAX..EDX)
        mov     edx, [esp+16+12+4+4] ;2nd incoming arg is Scratch
        lea     edx, [edx+esi*8]     ;Half-way Scratch.DoubleLengthResult
        mov     ebx, [esp+4]         ;F
        call    .DIF                 ;H-=F R+=F*m^2 -> (EAX ECX EBP)

        add     esp, 16              ;Finally discarding params

        imul    ecx, esi, 2
        mov     esi, edi             ;H
        mov     edi, [esp+12+4+4]    ;2nd incoming arg is Scratch
        lea     edi, [edi+ecx*2]     ;Quarter-way Scratch.DoubleLengthResult
        inc     ecx
@@:     lodsd                        ;R+=H*m
        adc     eax, [edi]
        stosd
        dec     ecx
        jnz     @b
@@:     mov     eax, [edi]
        adc     eax, ecx             ;ECX=0
        stosd
        jc      @b

        pop     ebp edi esi
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; Adds the coefficients of the number at EDX and stores the result in the
; double length buffer at EDI.
; IN (edx,esi,edi) OUT (edi,ebp) MOD (eax,ebx,edx)
.SUM:   mov     ebx, esi
        clc
@@:     mov     eax, [edx+esi*4]     ;First (c+d), later (a+b)
        adc     eax, [edx]
        stosd
        lea     edx, [edx+4]
        dec     ebx
        jnz     @b
        rcl     ebp, 1               ;Preserve overflow condition
        lea     edi, [edi+esi*4]     ;Skip high half for now
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; Cures the product in H if the sum of any 2 coefficients had an overflow.
; IN (ebx,esi,edi) OUT () MOD (eax,ebx,ecx,edx)
.CURE:  mov     ecx, esi
        mov     edx, edi
        lea     edi, [edi+esi*4]
        xchg    esi, ebx
        clc
@@:     lodsd
        adc     eax, [edi]
        stosd
        dec     ebx
        jnz     @b
        adc     [edi], ebx           ;EBX=0
        mov     edi, edx
        mov     esi, ecx
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; Moves the double length number at EBX to EDX
; at the same time subtracting it from the number at EDI.
; IN (ebx,edx,esi,edi) OUT () MOD (eax,ecx,ebp)
.DIF:   imul    ebp, esi, 2
        xor     ecx, ecx             ;CF=0
@@:     mov     eax, [ebx+ecx*4]     ;First H-G, later H-F
        mov     [edx+ecx*4], eax
        sbb     [edi+ecx*4], eax
        inc     ecx
        dec     ebp
        jnz     @b
        sbb     [edi+ecx*4], ebp     ;EBP=0
        ret
; ------------------------------------
```

Some interesting numbers to investigate, considering \$n = \log_2\text{Precision}\$

- Number of recursive `call`s

$$\sum_{i=5}^n 3^{i-5}$$

- Number of 'single-digit-multiplications'

$${3}^{n-5}$$

- Additional stack space needed once in *mpMul*

$$52+(n-5)*32$$

- Size of the required scratch buffer

$$\text{Precision}*\frac{3}{4}+(n-9)*4$$

---

I want to push this algorithm to its limits.
Did I miss some opportunity to do so?

Comment: What microarchitecture are you optimizing for?

Comment: @FUZxxl Sorry for the long delay but last weekend was a Belgian holiday. To answer your question: I wrote this code on an Intel® Pentium® dual-core processor T2080 and that would be Core™ microarchitecture. The instruction set goes up to SSE3 (not including SSSE3).

Comment: There's a typo - _Precission_ -> _Precision_. Otherwise: have you tried comparing your performance using hand-rolled assembly to that of a C program run through an optimizing compiler?

Comment: @Reinderien Sadly my skills in C (and anything similar) are really bad. But yes, such a comparison could be interesting. About the remaining typo: In the next weeks I will try to reproduce that screenshot and edit the post. Thanks for noticing.