# Multiplying big numbers using Long Multiplication

Tags: performance, algorithm, assembly, x86

Three weeks ago I posted [Multiplying big numbers using Karatsuba's method](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194309/multiplying-big-numbers-using-karatsubas-method) where I made reference to *my version of the classical long multiplication*. That's what I'm posting today so people can compare for themselves. At the same time I'm hoping someone still sees ways to further improve this code!

The multi-precision *mpMul* procedure that I present below requires 4 parameters passed on the stack.

- The 1st param specifies the precision (length in bits) of both the inputs which needs to be a multiple of 64.
- The 2nd param points to the 1st input aka multiplicand.
- The 3rd param points to the 2nd input aka multiplier.
- The 4th param points to where the **double length** result needs to go.

The address of the double length product is returned in the `EAX` register and the carry flag will be set if the result exceeds the precision.

I applied the following ideas:

- I detect leading and trailing zeroes beforehand. All leading zeroes can simply be ignored. For each trailing zero in the multiplicand or multiplier, a new trailing zero is inserted in the result.
- Since detecting embedded zeroes came at no apparant cost, appropriate shortcuts were installed.
- I let the shorter number control the outer loop, thus reducing the number of times the costlier inner loop has to run.
- I try to avoid having to enter the carry-loop as much as possible.

Computing MAX_UINT^2, the number of multiplications is \${4}^{(n-5)}\$ where \$n=\log_2\text{Precision}\$

[image: Computing MAX_UINT^2]

```
; -------------------------------------
; Multiplying using long multiplication
; -------------------------------------
; IN () OUT (eax,CF)
mpMul:  pushad
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     edx, [ebp+32+4]      ;IntSize {64, 128, 192, ...}
        shr     edx, 5               ;Bits -> dwords

        mov     edi, [ebp+32+4+12]   ;BufferC (double length result)
        mov     [ebp+28], edi        ;pushad.EAX
        push    edx edi              ;(1)

        imul    eax, edx, 8
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
.Wipe:  sub     eax, 16              ;Clear result buffer
        movdqu  [edi+eax], xmm0
        jnz     .Wipe

        mov     esi, [ebp+8+32+4+8]  ;BufferB (default multiplier)
        mov     ebx, [ebp+8+32+4+4]  ;BufferA (default multiplicand)
        call    .Prune               ; -> ECX ESI EDI
        xchg    ebx, esi
        mov     ebp, ecx
        call    .Prune               ; -> ECX ESI EDI

        cmp     ebp, ecx
        jbe     .MultiplierLoop      ;Multiplier 'is shorter' Multiplicand
        xchg    esi, ebx
        xchg    ecx, ebp
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.MultiplierLoop:
        cmp     dword [ebx], 0       ;Embedded zero in multiplier
        je      .Zero

        push    ecx esi edi          ;(2)
.MultiplicandLoop:
        add     edi, 4
        lods    dword [esi]
        test    eax, eax             ;Embedded zero in multiplicand
        jz      .Done
        mul     dword [ebx]
        add     [edi-4], eax
        adc     [edi], edx
        jnc     .Done
        adc     dword [edi+4], 0     ;(*) Avoid entering the carry-loop
        jnc     .Done
        mov     eax, edi
.Carry: add     eax, 4               ;The carry-loop
        add     dword [eax+4], 1     ;(*) +4
        jc      .Carry
.Done:  dec     ecx
        jnz     .MultiplicandLoop
        pop     edi esi ecx          ;(2)

.Zero:  add     edi, 4
        add     ebx, 4
        dec     ebp
        jnz     .MultiplierLoop
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.END:   pop     edi ecx              ;(1)
        lea     edi, [edi+ecx*4]     ;Middle of double length result
        xor     eax, eax
        repe scas dword [edi]        ;Defines CF

        popad
        ret     16
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; IN (eax=0,edx,esi,edi) OUT (ecx,esi,edi)
.Prune: mov     ecx, edx             ;Precision expressed as dwords (2+)
.Lead:  dec     ecx                  ;Skip leading zeroes
        js      .Quit                ;Multiplier and/or Multiplicand is 0
        cmp     [esi+ecx*4], eax     ;EAX=0
        je      .Lead
        inc     ecx                  ;Significant dwords
        cmp     [esi], eax           ;EAX=0
        jne     .Ready
.Trail: dec     ecx                  ;Skip trailing zeroes
        add     esi, 4               ;Skip low dwords that are zero
        add     edi, 4               ; by moving starting points upwards
        cmp     [esi], eax           ;EAX=0
        je      .Trail
.Ready: ret
.Quit:  pop     eax                  ;Forget 'call .Prune'
        jmp     .END
; -----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A**. These `EBP` relative displacements are wrong. They would have been correct if used in an `ESP` relative addressing.

> ```
>     mov     esi, [ebp+8+32+4+8]  ;BufferB (default multiplier)
>     mov     ebx, [ebp+8+32+4+4]  ;BufferA (default multiplicand)
> ```

---

**B**. The Intel optimization manual mentions:

> All branch targets should be 16-bytes aligned.

You could apply this and see what it does for your code.

---

**C**. I don't see any benefit from checking for embedded zeroes. I think those will be extremely rare.

> ```
> .MultiplicandLoop:
>     add     edi, 4
>     lods    dword [esi]
>     test    eax, eax             ;Embedded zero in multiplicand
>     jz      .Done
>     mul     dword [ebx]
> ```

If you remove the `test` and `jz` instructions from above code, you should insert some other (useful) instruction. Why? The hint is in what you said yourself:

> ...detecting embedded zeroes came at no apparant cost...

Meaning the code between `lods` and `mul` got executed for free!

```
.MultiplicandLoop:
    lods    dword [esi]
    add     edi, 4
    mul     dword [ebx]
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I made a last-minute change from `[esp]` to `[ebp]` and forgot those 2 displacements. Nice catch. Concerning **C.** I can report I got a 3% speed increase from applying that suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Some perf thoughts:

- [Using xchg reg,reg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45766444/2189500) is more expensive than you might expect.
- [pushad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48455374/2189500) isn't great either.
- I'm not sure how useful it might be here, but you might also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29748041/2189500).  This has to do with the issues related to chains of `addc`.
- And while people are [dubious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8429084/2189500) about `repe scas`, it probably isn't an issue here.
- It might also be interesting to run this thru [IACA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021338/2189500).  Something as simple as reversing two instructions can make a measurable difference.  It's *hard* for humans to write efficient asm anymore.  Apologies if you are actually an AI.  That's not as unlikely today as it once was.

It might also be interesting to write this in x64.  More registers, more bits per register.  There's got to be some benefit there somewhere, and x64 is pretty much the standard these days.

You were probably hoping for something a little more analytical about the algorithm itself, but this is what I've got.

---

Edit1:

A late breaking thought.  Since you already have a requirement that your inputs `needs to be a multiple of 64`, how about adding another one that says your memory pointers must be 64 byte aligned?  This allows you to replace `movdqu` with `movdqa`.  Tiny, but still.

Probably even tinier: I might experiment with changing `imul eax, edx, 8` to either `mov eax, edx ; shl eax, 3` or `lea eax, [edx * 8]`.  From a "length of instructions" viewpoint, imul is the clear winner.  From a "latency" perspective, perhaps less so.  IACA might give you this answer.  It's pretty good for answering questions like: Is `add esi, 4` better for my code *at this point* than `lea esi, [esi + 4]`?

Comment: All good thoughts. Too bad that all the interesting stuff like `mulx`, `adcx`, `adox`, and x64 registers isn't available on my computer. I certainly see how they would improve the code. Given that all the other suggestions pertain to the one-time prologue and epilogue code, I can't expect too much from applying them.